# Operator overloading and pointers to objects, c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've build a class representing a matrix and I override all
the arithmetic operators. Here's an example of overloading the unary minus

RegMatrix.h:

```
const RegMatrix operator - ();
```

RegMatrix.cpp

```
const RegMatrix RegMatrix::operator - ()
{
    RegMatrix newMatrix(*this);
    newMatrix *= -1;
    return newMatrix;
}
```

Now, this works perfect when I instantiate object on the stack like this: `RegMatrix a(3,3,v)` (v is a vector of values, doesn't matter).
When I use the `new` keyword like this (in main.cpp):

```
RegMatrix* a = new RegMatrix(3,3,v);
RegMatrix* b = -a; //<---ERROR HERE
```

I get `wrong type argument to unary minus`
Any ideas why this happens? Thanks!

P.S.
Another question: the '=' operator is automatically overridden by the copy constructor, right?

Comment: `operator=` is _not_ overriden by the copy constructor. You have to override it yourself. However, the copy constructor will be invoked if you use the `=` operator _at declaration_. Everywhere else, `operator=`is invoked.

Comment: @Etienne de Martel: `operator =` is not **overriden** but it is **overloaded**. The standard specifically requires the use of **virtual** keyword on a function to be **overriden**.

Comment: @Als Wooops. I always confuse these two terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `a` is `RegMatrix *`, not `RegMatrix`; if you want to apply operators on the object to which `a` points you have to dereference `a` (`*a`), apply the operator to it (`-(*a)`) and, if you want a separate instance of it on the heap, create a new copy of it on the heap with `new` and the copy constructor:

```
RegMatrix* a = new RegMatrix(3,3,v);
RegMatrix* b = new RegMatrix(-(*a));
```

Still, as @leftaroundabout pointed out in a comment, this is not a good way to work in C++, where, as a rule of thumb, you try to avoid dynamic allocation if you can (it's slower and it requires smart pointers if you don't want memory leaks).

Comment: It's always worth mentioning that this is usually not a very good way to do it, in C++.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes, I'll add a line about it.